# Getting exit value of a shell script 255 every time

Tags: java, shell, ksh

I have a jar say test.jar having TestJar as its main class, a shell script jar_executor.sh,and a java file. My test.jar will return 1 if we pass 1 as an argument and 2 if we pass any other value.
My shell script is executing test.jar as follow

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
java TestJar 1 -cp test.jar
return_code=$?
exit $return_code
```

In java file I am creating a process and executing shell script and taking its exitvalue with following code

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runtime.exec(sh jar_executor.sh);
int exitVal = process.waitFor();
System.out.println(exitVal);
```

This exitVal variable should print 1 or 2 as per argument we are passing but it is printing 255 everytime.
If I use `echo $return_code` in shell script then I am getting correct value.
Please help me why I am getting value 255 with `exit`. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: 255 means that the exit code is out reach, i think arguments are being passed together or something

Comment: A simpler way to do the shell script would be `set -e; java TestJar 1 -cp test.jar`. The -e option means that if any command exits with nonzero status, bash will immediately exit itself, also with that status. It's a bit like exception handling for shell script.

Answer (score 4):

255 or -1 is an application defined exit code, you would have to read the code to know what it means.

A Java application which exits normally, returns 0 and if it throws an Exception, returns 1.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your workspace library, workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench
and remove the workbench file :) . after that you can restart eclipse

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it might be a Java bug.  Others have reported issues similar to what you've seen; see this [Java bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6462682).  The Java devs don't think there's a bug but I'm suspicious.  The code JRE uses to get the return value from a spawned process is hairy, and I wouldn't be surprised if there's a race condition or other concurrency bug.

I'm guessing that the JRE fails to capture the return code if the spawned process exits very quickly.  If my suspicion is correct, adding `sleep 1` to your shell script will cause it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your shell script does not call java correctly:

```
java TestJar 1 -cp test.jar
```

You need to set the options for the java command before you mention your main class name. All arguments after your main class name are arguments for your main class and are no longer options for the java VM. So in your case there is no classpath specified for java. I get the following error message when I execute your script: **Error: Could not find or load main class TestJar**. To fix, you have just to re-order the arguments in your jar_executor.sh script:

```
java -cp test.jar TestJar 1
```

I cannot reproduce the 255 on my PC, so I can only guess where that comes from: Either your java command returns an error code of 255 instead of 1 when it fails to load the main class or your korn shell (/usr/bin/ksh) sets this return value when the script is aborted.

Here are all sources I used:

jar_executor.sh

```
#!/bin/sh -e

java -cp test.jar TestJar 2
return_code=$?
exit $return_code
```

TestJar.java

```
public class TestJar {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.exit(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
    }
}
```

JarRunner.java

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class JarRunner {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        final Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        final Process process = runtime.exec("sh jar_executor.sh");
        final int exitVal = process.waitFor();
        System.out.println(exitVal);
    }
}
```

When I now run `java -cp bin JarRunner`, I get the output **2** as expected.

Answer (score -1):

You're probably wrong in invoking the script. Try:

```
Process process = runtime.exec("sh -c jar_executor.sh");
```

Note the "-c" flag that means you're calling the shell to execute the command.

Comment: Adding the "-c" flag makes matters worse, because now the jar_executor.sh script needs the execute permission ("x-flag") as well. Without the "-c" flag, it works independently from the permissions of the shell script.